# Canvas drawline with semi transparent lines overlap problem

Tags: android, canvas

I am drawing several lines on a canvas using drawline, the lines are semi transparent (their paint has an alpha value <255) only problem is that the point at which they cross creates a dot of less transparent color (obviously) is there a simple way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Path and add your lines to the Path. This will prevent the "problem" you are seeing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047330/android-paint-how-to-get-airbrush-effect/17062021#17062021. could you take a look at the question and provide a solution if possible.